# How do I get ext3/ext4 filesystem features to apply in mke2fs?

Tags: filesystems, ext4, inode, ext3, mkfs

As many of you know, ext3/ext4 have filesystem features that make up the special functionalities that they have already, some of these features you can get them from "dumpe2fs", for example this output:

**Filesystem features: has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery extent flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file uninit_bg dir_nlink extra_isize**

So my question is, where in the system or which command can I use to get the full listing of filesystem features to apply when using mke2fs?

If anyone happens to know a useful website/link I'd appreciate it too.

Comment: If you read `mke2fs` man page it says _"For more information about the features which can be set, please see the manual page `ext4(5)`"_...

Comment: `cat /etc/mke2fs.conf` there are the Options your Distrie use for ext3 and ext4 filesystem.